# Basic Salesforce validation Rule formula

Tags: formula, validation

I need to create a validation rule to say if

Mailingcountry = canada then field Canada_Email_Consent__c needs to be completed

Canada_Email_Consent__c = Picklist
Mailingcountry = text

Comment: Do you use the State and Country pick list? it will give you easier validation options.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
AND(
     UPPER(MailingCountry) = 'CANADA',
     ISBLANK(TEXT(Canada_Email_Consent__c))
)
```

Comment: What happens if they spell Canada, upper/lower case etc?

Comment: You can use both.  All UPPER does is make it not case specific.  So canada and cAnAdA would both be captured in tehis rule.  You can combine the two functionas though.  CONTAINS(UPPER(MailingCountry), 'CANADA')

Comment: 'CANANDA' ?  Are you sure you don't mean 'CANADA' ?

Comment: Yeah yes, it is a typo. No wonder why it wasnt working :P
I appreciate your help guys.